# Elementary Probability

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble figuring this homework problem out:

If you flip $10$ nickels all at the same time, what is the probability that exactly $3$ will come up heads and $7$ will come up tails?

Obviously for $1$ coin toss the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ and the probability that all $10$ will be heads or tails is $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ or $\frac{1}{1024}$. But how do I set it up to find out the solution to the problem above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the probability that all $10$ will be heads or tails is
>   $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$ or $\frac{1}{1024}$

That's the probability of getting $10$ heads. The probability of getting $10$ heads or tails would be $$2\cdot\frac{1}{2^{10}}=\frac{1}{2^{9}}$$

For the question at hand, use the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). Let $X$ denote the number of heads. Then

$$P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

where $n$ is the number of trials, $k$ is the number of successes, and $p$ is the probability of a success on an individual trial.

Comment: In R statistical software, `dbinom(3, 10, .5)` returns 0.1171875, and
`choose(10, 3)/2^10` returns exactly the same thing. The latter explicitly implements @Remy's formula with $n=10, k=3, p=.5.$ There are ${10 \choose 3} = \frac{10!}{3!\cdot 7!} = 120$ ways to arrange 3 H's and 7 T's in a row: HHHTTTTTTT, HHTHTTTTTT, etc. [If you have what you need, please click the check mark to Accept Remy's answer. If not, please try to explain your confusion. // You will get the best response here if you show as much as possible of what you have tried.]